# Ubuntu installation from HDD

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

I am using a notebook without a CD burner and want to install Ubuntu. I could use an USB stick as an installation medium but I would like to do something different:

I would like to use my old PC and put the HDD from the laptop into it. Than make this HDD as a installation medium using a Ubuntu DVD (the old PC has a CD burner). In the next step I would like to put the prepared HDD into the laptop and install Ubuntu on the same HDD (from the same HDD).
Is something like this possible?